# Why does my Websocket Server need manual refreshing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, windows-server-2016

In order to add a chatting function to my website, I set up a Websocket server using node.js on a Windows 2016 server. I was able to establish a successful connection between my client and server and the application is working pretty smoothly.

However, every once in a while, the connection will appear to freeze and the client will send a message to the socket but the socket seems to be frozen until I refresh it by clicking on the command prompt on my server computer.

At first, I thought it was a connection issue but all the appropriate ports appear to be open and I am convinced that it is a server issue.

I am a beginning coder so I'm sorry if I am not using the proper terminology but help would be much appreciated. If anything is unclear I will add more info.

Thanks!